# How to change the Gmail plain text font in the compose textbox?

Tags: gmail, fonts, fixed-width

How can I force Gmail to use a font I like in the compose textbox? I compose emails using plain text mode, not the rich text mode.

Browser: Firefox
OS: Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a Stylish user style for this: [**Gmail - Fixed Width Font**](http://userstyles.org/styles/22978).

Answer (score 4):

Install the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) script [Gmail Fixed Font](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/17869).

By default it installs as `monospaced` so you will have to edit the following line in the script to the font face and size of your liking:

```
var css = ".ii, .dV { font: .9em monospace !important; }";
```

If you wanted to increase the font size a little and type up in Futura font, it would look like this:

```
var css = ".ii, .dV { font: 1em futura important; }";
```

After you do, restart Firefox and log back into your Gmail account. Now you can compose emails in the font of your choice.

A side-effect is that it will also change the font of the emails in your inbox to what you have edited.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have the best luck writing a script to do it yourself in the browser - I don't believe there's an option you can set within the system to specify this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to tell the browser to use a different font. Specifically for an element of type textarea. How you do this depends on what browwser you're using, and possibly what Operating System as well.

Comment: Assume it is Firefox on Windows.